# Size of Node Class in Linked List coming out to be 16?

Tags: c++, linked-list, size

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node

{

    public:

        int data;

        Node *next;

};

int main()

{   

    Node* re=new Node();

    Node* t=new Node();

    re->data=2;

    re->next=t;

    cout<<sizeof(Node)<<endl;

    cout<<sizeof(re->data)<<endl;

    cout<<sizeof(re->next)<<endl;

}
```

Ouput:

16

4

8

How come the size of the class is coming out to be 16.

I get how the size of pointer is 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine and 4 bytes for 
integer. So shouldn't the size of the class be 12 (8 + 4) i.e. sum of the members of the class?
Why there is an extra 4?

Comment: It's called padding. Assuming a 64 bit operating system, the `next` member must be 8-byte aligned, so there's 4 bytes of padding between the `int` and the pointer in each instance.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler adds extra space for alignment. So called memory padding. 
Here's a detailed explanation of it: [padding and packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)